# How to edit results.aspx (not using SPD or code) on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I'm trying to apply a result source to the Search Results Web Part on the results page of my Basic Search Centre subsite. I'm using SharePoint Online.
I don't see Edit Page as an option and therefore can't do it.

Is there an alternative now that things have changed?

C

Answer (score 1):

Found out. Nothing to do with SPO or the new modern experience. I was using the Basic Search Centre and not the Enterprise Search Centre.

Comment: Yep, don't use the basic search center template unless you really don't want to change anything. Also, every SPO tenant already has a Enterprise Search Center provisioned under the Search managed path. https://tenant.sharepoint.com/search